# Qt Creator cannot find the main function

Tags: c++, qt-creator, program-entry-point

I have a C++ project loaded into Qt Creator 4.5.2.

I have a header-only library, and a test project that tests the library. The test project has a clear `main` function.

The test project builds correctly. When I run the produced executable from console it works as expected, however Qt Creator fails to run or debug the test project with the following error:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:-1: In function `_start':
>
> (.text+0x20):-1: error: undefined reference to `main' :-1: error:
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have looked in SO, and all I have found is people who forgot to write their main function, which is not my case.

**What is going on here? How can I fix it?**

My main function is quite straight forward:

```
#include "test_math.h"
#include "test_engine.h"

/**
* @brief main
* @return
*/
int main() {

    std::cout << "GridCal++ tests" << std::endl;

    gce_test::sp_submatrix_test();

    //gce_test::sp_mat_test(makeA, makeb);

    gce_test::sp_submatrix_test();

    gce_test::graph_test();

    gce_test::test_engine_1();

    gce_test::test_engine_wei_min();

    gce_test::test_lynn_5bus();
    
    gce_test::state_stimation_test();

    gce_test::test_psse_file();

    gce_test::test_json();

    std::cout << "\n\nAll tests done." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit." << std::endl;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    return 0;
}
```

The `.pro` of the project that has `main.cpp` is:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG -= qt

TARGET = GridCal_tests
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# remove possible other optimization flags
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2

# add the desired -O3 if not present
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O3


TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/../GridCal"
INCLUDEPATH += "$$PWD/../libs/armadillo/include"

unix {

    # Intel MKL (Linux)
    # Use https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor
    # to configure the include directived for Intel MKL

#    MKLROOT = /opt/intel/mkl
#    INCLUDEPATH += $${MKLROOT}/include

    # MKL linking options: Static | 32-bit integer  interface layer | OpenMP threading
#    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -m64
#    LIBS += -Wl,--start-group $${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a $${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl

    # MKL linking options: Static | 64-bit integer  interface layer | OpenMP threading
    # Seems not to be suited for the problem since it cannot solve spsolve...
#    LIBS +=  -Wl,--start-group $${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a $${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a $${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl
#    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DMKL_ILP64 -m64


    # OpenBlas (static linking for GCC Linux)
    LIBS += "$$PWD/../libs/lib_linux64/openblas/lib/libopenblas.a"
    LIBS += -lpthread -lgfortran
}
win32 {

    # Intel MKL (Windows with MS C/C++ compiler)
    # Use https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor
    # to configure the include directived for Intel MKL


    MKLROOT = /opt/intel/mkl
    INCLUDEPATH += $${MKLROOT}/include

    # MKL linking options: Static | 32-bit integer interface layer | OpenMP threading
    #LIBS += mkl_intel_lp64.lib mkl_intel_thread.lib mkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib

    # MKL linking options: Static | 64-bit integer interface layer | OpenMP threading
    LIBS +=  mkl_intel_ilp64.lib mkl_intel_thread.lib mkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /DMKL_ILP64
}

HEADERS += \
    test_engine.h \
    test_math.h

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

message($$INCLUDEPATH)
message($$LIBS)
```

Comment: We need to see your project file (`.pro`) to diagnose this problem. Though I suspect the problem is trying to build a "header-only library". In this case, there's no binary target for Qt to build or run, hence the linker error. It's probably trying to build a library target (not the test binary). Compiling your header on its own into a static or shared library doesn't make sense. The project file will show us what's going on.

Comment: I have just added the .pro of the project I want to compile. The project itself is not header-only, but it uses a header-only library within the project.

Comment: How do you build it? You can't get `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` when running/debugging, this is a compilation/linking error. If you post what the **Compile Output** tab in QtCreator is showing, should help to diagnose what is going on.

Comment: Can't reproduce!!! First create auto-generated console application and then add one by one library and header files and check at which point you start facing error.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no compilation error, the compilation is fine. I have a parallel VS project with the same code that works perfectly. The problem is in the Qt IDE itself or maybe the .pro configuration or some option or something IDE related.

Comment: Have you tried `int main(int argc, char **argv)`? As `QApplication` wants to parse the arguments, Qt might not support the `()` variant.

Comment: still not working :(